# Transition UIviewControllers

Tags: ios

I would like to change UIviewController with the press of a button. The animation has to last +-0.5sec. and has to go from right to left. So the old viewcontroller must slide out to let the new one in, a big like this:

```
MainView.frame = CGRectMake(self.MainView.frame.origin.x - 768,self.MainView.frame.origin.y, self.MainView.frame.size.width, self.MainView.frame.size.height);
```

...but to use this code I would need to create a UIcontainerView, which in my opinion isn't the best way of doing it because it will fill up memory as the old view isn't deallocated. furthermore in the new view controller I have other container views. What is the best approach?

Comment: The best method for this is using a UINavigationController. Are you using a navigation controller? You can also create a custom transition/segue so that it moves in 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Nom great idea though. I am using storyboard, and in storyboard there is a bar at the top of the nag. controller. How can I remove that bar?

Comment: Could you perhaps take some time to read the documentation about UINavigationController?

Comment: Found it [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is a great way of approaching the problem